# arrays overlapping in a union?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class:

```
template <typename T, ::std::size_t M, ::std::size_t N>
struct matrix
{
private:
  union
  {
    T idata[M * N];
    T data[M][N];
  } u_;
};
```

I use the `idata` union member to initialize the matrix and the `data` member for access. The two arrays seem to overlap exactly in my use-case. Does the standard guarantee that this will always be the case? That is, that both `u_.idata` and `u_.data` will have the same starting address and the same size?

EDIT:

I use this `constexpr` constructor to initialize the matrix:

```
template <typename ...U>
constexpr matrix(U&&... args) : u_{{::std::forward<U>(args)...}}
{
}
```

Without the union I would have no way to initialize the matrix in a `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: It's a bit tricky. Both arrays are guaranteed to take up the same amount of space, but you're not allowed to read an inactive union member, and you're also not allowed to overstep an array bound. A compiler *could* detect the UB and just optimize your entire code away.

Comment: Since "a pointer to a union, suitably converted, points to all of its members", I think it is guaranteed. However, you can't access one member of a union after writing to the other one, since that's undefined behavior.

Comment: The way `union` and multidimensional arrays are specified guarantee that the two arrays will be overlapping (and, in particular, that idata[M*y+x] refers to the same address of data[y][x]), but I don't know if they qualify for the "common initial subsequence" thing, which would allow to use both `union` members at the same time.

Comment: @H2CO3 For me it's the only way to expand a parameter pack into the matrix in a `constexpr` constructor.

Comment: I once discussed with a Clang developer and CWG guy the simpler question whether `T a[M][N]; for (i = 0; i != M * N; ++i) a[0][i];` was OK, and he reckoned that a compiler might simply say, "out of bounds access, UB", and do whatever it wanted, e.g. remove the entire loop. Semi-relatedly, Clang has ubsan, a UB-detector, and I believe they're trying to exploit UB very eagerly.

Comment: Please post your actual problem; I should like to believe that we can find a proper solution.

Comment: @KerrekSB: AFAIK, to pull that kind of stunt one would do `T *p=a;` and then work with `p`. I remember something in the array FAQ about this.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: That wouldn't compile, since `a` is a `T(*)[M]`, not a `T*`. At best you could have `T * p = &a[0][0]` and use `p[i]` (which is essentially what I was doing).

Comment: Personally, I would add a few `static_assert`s to check whether the starting- and ending-addresses of the first and last row are the same and be done with it.

Comment: If those arrays were layout-compatible, accessing through either of them would even be defined behaviour. If they had the same alignment requirements, that might even be the case *in layman's terms*. The Standard doesn't contain a definition of *layout-compatible* for arrays, as far as I can see.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, that would be &a[0][0]. I think that the question boils down to whether in §5.7 ¶5, when saying "point to elements of the same array object" it can be interpreted to refer to the whole multidimensional array, or just to the row-subarrays. I fear that the latter may be the case, but I'd like to be wrong (since that would be a stupid and arbitrary restriction, given that the rest of the standard already mandates contiguous, row-wise arrays).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I think you can make a fairly clear case that `a[0][0]` is the first element of a array of `N` elements, and so `a + i` is only permitted for `i` in the range `[0, N]`, by the usual rules of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @KerrekSB: For `int (*p)[N]`, yes (limited to the range `0..m`).  But  `int* p` is not so limited, so can use any offset that lands in the same complete object.

Comment: "Without the union I would have no way to initialize the matrix in a constexpr constructor." You can very well initialize a multi-array with one pair of braces: `int arr[2][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};`

Comment: @DyP I'll go and see, could be a bug in my compiler, yeah, this is called brace elision? `gcc-4.8.1` does not support this fully, I think.

Comment: @DyP Write last comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not that sure of what you are saying... If `T` is a standard layout type, then the code is perfectly fine and guaranteed

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: How so? What exactly makes it legal to overstep the array bounds?

Comment: @BenVoigt: How does that follow? Surely not just from pointer arithmetic? Maybe something to do with `offsetof`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: the point is that such arrays does not seem to be not layout compatible.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It follows from the rules of pointer arithmetic.  Both the original and result pointers point into the same array object.  The array object is `a` and has type `int[M][N]`.  (You cannot interpret 5.7/5 to mean "exactly the start of an element" since that would preclude using `char*` arithmetic inside objects, which we know is allowed, and therefore that interpretation is ruled out)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not convinced. Any given `int` inside the `int[M][N]` lives inside an array of type `int[N]`, not an array of type `int[M * N]` (and the outer array is an array of arrays, not an array of ints), and so you can move a pointer to it by at most `N`. How exactly are you allowed to move it by a larger amount?

Comment: Pointer `p` and `p + i*N + j` both point to the array object `a` with type `int[M][N]`.  `p` points into the first element (`a[0]`) and `p + i*N + j` points into the (i+1)th element, `a[i]`.  Remember that the data type of `p` is not the same as the data type of `a[i]`, so the range of valid indexes on `p` need not be the same either.

Comment: I now looked into the C99 Standard, and it says in 6.7.5.2/6 "For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value." So I guess they're *not* layout-compatible in C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But that's begging the question - I'm disputing whether you're even *allowed* to evaluate `p + i*N + j`. I agree that `p` points into `a[0]` (and *at* `a[0][0]`), but in my reading of 5.7/5 I question whether "both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object" -- since as you just said, `p + i*N + j` points (or maybe, "would point") into `a[i]` and not into `a[0]`, which are *not* the same array object.

Comment: @Kerrek: Huh?  `a[0]` is an element of `a`, an array object.  `a[i]` is an element of `a`, the same array object.  Therefore according to 5.7/5 pointer arithmetic can produce a pointer into `a[i]` from a pointer into `a[0]`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But surely only with a pointer of the type of `a[0]`, not of `a[0][0]`?!

Comment: The stricter interpretation you're trying to use would outlaw `((char*)p)+1)`.  But we know that *isn't* undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: We know, though, that `*p` can be interpreted as an array of characters, that's guaranteed...

Comment: @Kerrek: Where?  What's guaranteed (3.10/10) is that you can use an lvalue of type (cv-qualified) `char&` to access a byte inside any object.  But first you need to be able to form the lvalue, which requires abiding by the pointer arithmetic rules.  (It's not legal to use a `char*` to move through memory willy-nilly, you have to treat every object separately)  And how does that make the pointer arithmetic to move through all of `a` using `char*` legal?  I think 5.7/5 makes it legal, because `((char*)p)` and `((char*)p)+M*N*sizeof(int)` are both pointers into/one past the same array object `a`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think what makes it legal is that you can treat an object of type `T` as an array of `sizeof(T)` bytes by 3.9/4, and with `T = int[M][N]`, you get an array of `sizeof(int) * M * N` elements. I think that doesn't contradict the rule about pointer arithmetic needing to stay within the same array: *every* object can be seen as an array of bytes.

Comment: @Kerrek: 3.9/2 lets you copy into a `char[sizeof(T)]`, but 3.9/4 doesn't say anything about arrays.  It says sequence of `char` objects, but `int[M][N]` absolutely also is a sequence of `M*N` `int` objects.  Of course, if it does mean usage as `char[sizeof (T)]` then you're back to `p+i*N+j` being allowed, since original and result both point into the same `char[N*M*sizeof(int)]`.

Comment: I don't see any possible interpretation that allows `char*` arithmetic through an `int[M][N]`, but not `int*` arithmetic throughout the whole `M*N` sequence as well.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I disagree. Given `int a[10][20];`, and `int *p = &a[0][0];` the language guarantees that `(p+10)` is a safely derived pointer to one beyond the last element of the first nested array. It also guarantees that it is a pointer to the first element in the second nested array, and that in turn guarantees that you can further increment by 10 to get to one beyond the second nested array, which itself is the first element of the third nested array... the properties of addition guarantee the rest.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: sort it out with Ben Voigt and Kerrek SB, I'm here with the popcorns. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Without the union I would have no way to initialize the matrix in a `constexpr` constructor.

Actually, you could.  You just have to stop thinking of the flat array as merely a workaround for construction.

This will work:

```
template <typename T, ::std::size_t M, ::std::size_t N>
struct matrix
{
  template <typename ...U> constexpr matrix(U&&... args);
private:
  T idata[M * N];
  constexpr T& data( size_t i, size_t j ) { return idata[i*N+j]; }

  // I'm sure the class has many other useful members but I'm not listing them
};
```

The compiler should generate the same code for that, too.

Comment: How so, since `no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11)` for aggregates? This would be a limiting factor for me.

Comment: I mean, _you_ should not have provided any private members, or aggregate initialization will not work, as far as I understand.

Comment: There's no limitation on having private members in a type that's `constexpr`-usable.  `matrix` isn't an aggregate, its `idata` member is, and can be initialized in a `constexpr` constructor as you desired, using the technique you showed in your question.

Comment: @user: It was not intended to be a complete definition of the type, just the parts shown in your question.  Your question had a constructor that wasn't declared in the class body.  I did the same.  I was only showing that `data` could be an inline function instead of a data member, without making any changes to your `constexpr` constructor.